# Replicating cells in Excel VBA : Drop box and formula interaction

Tags: excel, vba

**QUESTION 1:** How to write a VBA code in order to accomplish this task and, most importantly, replicate the formulas to all cells of column N ?

- Column L, starting from line 13 (L13). In this column the user will inform the currency, by selecting from a drop box located in each cell, an array of three possibilities. They are letters and defined as the word "Real" or "Dollar" or "Euro")
- Column M, starting from line 13. Here the user will imput a number
- Column N, also starting from line 13. This column will calculate the investment. The properties of the cells in this column are set to "currency")
- I$3=2,42 (constant Dollar)
- I$4=3,30 (constant Euro)
- Column J, starting from line 13. This is the quantity of items being analysed (corn grains, rice bags etc)

Programming Algorithm
     ==================

*The code will check if the word "Real" or "Dollar" or "Euro" is present in cells of column L.*
*If "Dollar" is there, then it will multiply constant Dollar times the number the user prompted*
*(value of goods) times the quantity in the cells of column M. The outcome will be placed in cells of column N, which are always in "Real"*

If L13="Dollar" Then
N13=J13*M13*I$3

Else

If L13="Real" Then
N13=J13*M13

Else

If L13="Euro" Then
N13=J13*M13*I$4

Else

N13="0" and M13="0"

**QUESTION 2:** Also concerning drop boxes, suppose I want to have the total amount in column N and its cells will be added up only if they individually match some criteria. Here is the example where the user picks up a symbol inherited from a drop box (4 possible Wigdings symbols: I, &, x, þ)

Z1=SUMIF(B13:B300;"=þ";N13:N300)

(interval; criteria; interval sum). This means that the single cell Z1 encompasses the total amount of all cells pertaining to column N, with the condition that column B possesses the aforementioned symbols. Yet, this does not work. It Always gives me the value zero. Interesting, however, is to notice that if I replace (I, &, x, þ) by letters (a, b, c, d) the Z1 receives a non zero value. Not all letters work, as we can see by the letter "x" above.

Comment: Um... what is your specific problem?

Comment: If `A5 = "Real"` shouldn't the assignment be `Dn = Bn / E$1`.  Do you want a formula so a calculated value changes if the user changes the source value?  If the source values will not be changed, VBA could calculate the values rather than plant formulae.

Comment: After some trials and errors, I have managed to come up with a solution. See below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**Q1: SOLUTION**

```
  Sub Invest()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim cell As Range

  Sheets("Invest").Select    


  Range("N13").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=(RC[-4])*(IF(RC[-2]=""Dolar"",RC[-1]*R3C[-5],IF(RC[-2]=""Real"",_
          RC[-1],IF(RC[-2]=""Euro"",RC[-1]*R4C[-5],AND(0,RC[-1]=0)))))"
```

*this translates what is written above*
*=J13*(SE(L13="Dolar";M13*I$3;SE(L13="Real";M13;SE(L13="Euro";M13*I$4;E(0;M13=0)))))*

```
  t = Cells(1048576, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N13:N" & t), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

*The part above is very nice. It searches for data in column B until the last row of B1048576. If, for instance, column has some data till cell B300, then it will count how many cells there are between B300 and B13. Therefore, it will then copy the formula from N13 to N300. However, one should keep in mind that replication of formulas in a WorkBook full of sheets and several hundreds of rows can increase a lot the final size of the excel file. An alternative is to copy the outcome of the last calculation and paste special it in the same location, as value. As for example :*

```
Range("N13:N" & t).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("N13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

---

**Q2: SOLUTION**

*Do not use "=". It will then be:*

```
  Z1=SUMIF(B13:B300;"þ";N13:N300)
```

*In an English version of MSOffice you will use commas instead of semicolon*

*Well, that´s it.
See ya, Luiz*